# Dicas de como fazer um campo de busca com Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, algoritmo-de-busca

Preciso de dicas de como criar um campo de busca no Wordpress, eu tenho um pouco de conhecimento na plataforma, mas ainda muito limitado e não sei por onde começar.

O campo de busca é composto por estado, cidade e bairro, eu li vários tutoriais ensinando de como fazer um campo de busca, mas nenhum deles (que eu tenha achado) explica como fazer uma pesquisa com mais de um campo. Essas informações de estado, cidade e bairro são cadastradas por campos personalizados num post_type que eu criei.

Eu não tenho código ainda, porque eu realmente não sei por onde começar. Preciso de dicas, informações, links, qualquer coisa que me dê um "norte".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A busca padrão do WordPress sempre começa com um request `GET` contendo a chave `s`:

```
www.example.com/?s=gatinhos
```

faz uma busca por "gatinhos" no banco. A busca padrão só procura os dados nos campos `post_title` e `post_content` dos tipos `Post` e `Page`.

Beleza, então pra buscar nos campos adicionais você precisa interceptar essa busca antes que ela chegue ao banco e enviar as informações necessárias:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'intercepta_busca' );
```

A action `pre_get_posts` roda antes de rodas as consultas então a gente delimita o que quer dentro dela:

```
function intercepta_busca( $query ) {

    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {
        // pronto, agora sabemos que as modificações só ocorrerão
        // na consulta principal dentro de uma busca no front-end:

        $query->set( 'post_type', array( SEU_POST_TYPE ) );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR' // aceita AND/OR: use somente se tiver mais de 1 campo
            array(
                'key' => NOME_DO_CAMPO,
                'value' => $query->query_vars['s']
            ),
            // se for buscar por mais campos, inclua um array 
            // para cada par key/value
            array(
                'key' => NOME_DO_OUTRO_CAMPO,
                'value' => $query->query_vars['s']
            ),
        ) );
    }

}
```

E pronto. No exemplo acima a busca vai retornar todos os posts em `SEU_POST_TYPE` contendo o termo de busca no titulo ou no corpo E em `NOME_DO_CAMPO` ou `NOME_DO_OUTRO_CAMPO`

Comment: Perfeito, Ricardo. Era disso que eu precisava, irei implementar seguindo a sua recomendação. Agradeço humildemente.